# How do I install node 9 with nvm?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Trying but failing; also open to manual install if someone can help.

FYI, end goal is to install mobius-network-js to begin dev on a Mobius DApp

Comment: what commands you are running and where it is failing? what is the error? Please provide necessary information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install node `v9.0.0`, use

```
nvm install 9.0.0
```

Then check the version

```
node -v
```

It should be `v9.0.0`

If there is a version mismatch, use

```
nvm use 9.0.0
```

The output should be
`Now using node v9.0.0 (npm v5.5.1)`

> Made sure, you have already installed the `nvm`

You can also check the [Documentation](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can install specific version on node using nvm via

`nvm install <node-version>` - [nvm documentation](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage)

if you want to install node v9. you can run `nvm install v9` and this will automatically install
the node v9.x.x

you can also set it as the default version via the `nvm use` command.

Answer (score 0):

Open git bash and and try the following commands:

nvm install [version_needed]

nvm use [version_needed]

Instead of [version_needed] write down the relevant version of nodejs:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score -1):

**n** library is best alternative of nvm and its really easy to use .

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

installation step

step 1 -

> npm i n -g

step 2 -

> n node-version
>
> ex - n 9 or n stable to download latest stable version of node